# Reload iFrame Success Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reload my iframe then scroll back to the position it was previously in before reloading.

```
var iframe_x=$('#the-frame').attr("xpos");
        var iframe_y=$('#the-frame').attr("ypos");
        $('#the-frame').attr("src", $('#the-frame').attr("src"));
        document.getElementById('the-frame').contentWindow.scrollTo(iframe_x,iframe_y);
```

The problem is that we need to wait for the iFrame to finish loading before scrolling. Is there a 'success' function for attr?

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: If same domain then you have `document.getElementById('the-frame').onload = function() { code here; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use jquery's load event for this:

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```
$('#the-frame').load(function() { /* do some stuff */ });
```

**edit**
looks like that is deprecated as of 1.8 so it may make more sense to use

```
$('#the-frame').on('load', function() { /* do some stuff */ });
```

for future-proofing

Comment: Hmm sorry , Can you show me how I can integrate that into my code? 

I am reloading when the user presses a button. If I use this code, Doesnt this mean that I will get a memory leak if the user presses the button multiple times since I am continually binding the event?

Comment: Unless you are replacing the DOM element itself you should only need to set up the event handler once.